# How to set session value at startup page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Im am trying to set a session value at my startup page or when I first visit my webapp and change it when the user login. How to to this?

Comment: This Introduction to Java Session Management should help http://java.sys-con.com/node/37125

Comment: You can use a [session scoped bean](http://inheritingjava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/chapter-42-scope-of-javabeans-in-jsp.html).

Answer (score 0):

Session tracking is done using any of the following ways.

```
1.Using cookies (HttpSession)
2.Using URLrewriting
3.Hidden form fields
```

I'll discuss only the first option as it's the most common. It uses the [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html), a higher level API available with any Java EE implementation.

In login/start page,

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("username",username);
```

In other pages,

```
if(session.getAttribute("username")==null)
{
//forward to login page.
}
```